# Scrolling Notepad using C# and WIN32

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winapi

I'm trying to scroll a Notepad window using a C# application. The relevant code block is below, the call to move/size the window works so I know the handle is valid

please can you see what I am missing nothing happens when this is run.

```
    [Flags]
    public enum SetWindowPosFlags : uint
    {
        SWP_ASYNCWINDOWPOS = 0x4000,
        SWP_DEFERERASE = 0x2000,
        SWP_DRAWFRAME = 0x0020,
        SWP_FRAMECHANGED = 0x0020,
        SWP_HIDEWINDOW = 0x0080,
        SWP_NOACTIVATE = 0x0010,
        SWP_NOCOPYBITS = 0x0100,
        SWP_NOMOVE = 0x0002,
        SWP_NOOWNERZORDER = 0x0200,
        SWP_NOREDRAW = 0x0008,
        SWP_NOREPOSITION = 0x0200,
        SWP_NOSENDCHANGING = 0x0400,
        SWP_NOSIZE = 0x0001,
        SWP_NOZORDER = 0x0004,
        SWP_SHOWWINDOW = 0x0040,
    }


    private const int WM_SCROLL = 276; // Horizontal scroll
    private const int WM_VSCROLL = 277; // Vertical scroll
    private const int SB_LINEUP = 0; // Scrolls one line up
    private const int SB_LINELEFT = 0;// Scrolls one cell left
    private const int SB_LINEDOWN = 1; // Scrolls one line down
    private const int SB_LINERIGHT = 1;// Scrolls one cell right
    private const int SB_PAGEUP = 2; // Scrolls one page up
    private const int SB_PAGELEFT = 2;// Scrolls one page left
    private const int SB_PAGEDOWN = 3; // Scrolls one page down
    private const int SB_PAGERIGTH = 3; // Scrolls one page right
    private const int SB_PAGETOP = 6; // Scrolls to the upper left
    private const int SB_LEFT = 6; // Scrolls to the left
    private const int SB_PAGEBOTTOM = 7; // Scrolls to the upper right
    private const int SB_RIGHT = 7; // Scrolls to the right
    private const int SB_ENDSCROLL = 8; // Ends scroll


    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    private static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    static extern bool SetWindowPos(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hWndInsertAfter, int X, int Y, int cx, int cy, SetWindowPosFlags uFlags);



    public void scroll()
    {


        IntPtr handle = IntPtr.Zero;

        Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("Notepad");

        foreach (Process p in processes)
        {
            handle = p.MainWindowHandle;

            Console.WriteLine("Got Handle: " + p.MainWindowTitle);

            break;
        }

        //this is to test I have a valid handle
        SetWindowPos(handle, new IntPtr(0), 10, 10, 1024, 350, SetWindowPosFlags.SWP_DRAWFRAME);


        SendMessage(handle, WM_VSCROLL,  (IntPtr)SB_LINEDOWN, IntPtr.Zero);
        SendMessage(handle, WM_VSCROLL, (IntPtr)SB_PAGEDOWN, IntPtr.Zero);

    }
```

Comment: Just curious, why do you want to control notepad from a C# application?

Comment: "Nothing happens": so you don't get the message "Got Handle: x", you don't move the window successfully?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This fails because you are sending the WM_VSCROLL message to the main window.  You need to send the message to Notepad's edit control, which is the window with the scrollbar.

You can enumerate Notepad's child windows using [EnumChildWindows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633494%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  The child with class "Edit" is the one you want.

Comment: thanks thats great for Notepad, any ideas for an Outlook 2010 Message window? Iterayed through all the children but non will scroll the message down?

Comment: @Tekhoi: Use spy++ to investigate how Outlook's UI is constructed (I don't have Outlook myself so I can't have a look).